# Why does Spring security fire AuthenticationSuccessEvent even if maximum sessions limit is exceeded?

Tags: java, spring-security

I would expect that the [AuthenticationSuccessEvent](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/event/AuthenticationSuccessEvent.html) is not fired if the authentication was not successful, but I get this event even if the maximum sessions limit is exceeded and the [SessionAuthenticationException](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/SessionAuthenticationException.html) is thrown.

Java Configuration:

```
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .failureUrl("/login_failed.jsp")
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
}
```

Logging:

```
<13:01:31,002> <WARN > <LoggerListener> - Authentication event AuthenticationSuccessEvent: dur; details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@43458: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 1e7l0cf6q88j91wg2b8aw527na
<13:01:31,002> <DEBUG> <DefaultRedirectStrategy> - Redirecting to '/login_failed.jsp'
```

Is there any reason for that behavior and how can I log this case?

Comment: And why shouldn't it. Authentication was succesful and further down the chain the user is blocked due to a session already being present. TO be able to even check this fact the user needs to be authenticated.

Comment: @M. Deinum: Is it not strange to fire AuthenticationSuccessEvent and than run the AuthenticationFailureHandler? Anyway, is it possible to log this case (with an event)?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are implementing your own user repository and UserDetails implementation.

The principal is a UserDetails instance, so if you implements UserDetails the equals() and hashcode() should be overridden. Otherwise, the strategy will not work.

Comment: The strategy works fine and I'm not logged in, but the event was published.